# Plugin for Pocket Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-mobile

Is it possible to create a plugin for Pocket IE (I'm running Windows Mobile 6.1 Pro on a Samsung Omnia i900 device) using VS.Net 2008, C#. I want a menu option in the browser that when its selected it sends the current URL that I'm at to a mobile program - doesn't matter if the program is running or not. The program can then take the URL and do whatever with it.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Pocket IE is a native app, and since the CF doesn't support CLR Hosting, it cannot create managed objects.  You can write COM components for PIE, but they have to be done in C++.